# How to forward or move to home activity from login activity after user is authenticated over internet?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-intent

Here below is the class which sends users details to php file and after successfull login the echo statements are shown in AlertDialog box. So this works very well...

**BackgroundActivity.java**

```
package com.example.weblogin;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx =ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://10.0.0.2/androidapp/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://10.0.0.2/androidapp/login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to forward the user to the next activity or home activity after a successful login or once user is authenticated...
Below is the Login Activity(MainActivity) code...

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.weblogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    EditText ET_NAME,ET_PASS;
    String login_name,login_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
        ET_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
    }
    public void userReg(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
    }
    public void userLogin(View view)
    {
        login_name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        login_pass = ET_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method = "login";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,login_name,login_pass);

    }
}
```

and this is my php file which returns some statements which are then shown in AlertDialog...

**Login.php**

```
<?php  
 require "../dbconnect.php";  
 $user_name = $_POST["login_name"];  
 $user_pass =  $_POST["login_pass"];  
 $sql_query = "select Firstname,Lastname from users where emailid like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";  
 $result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql_query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
 {  
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
 $name =$row["Firstname"]." ".$row["Lastname"];  
 echo "Login Success..Welcome ".$name;  
 }  
 else  
 {   
 echo "Login Failed.......Try Again..";  
 }  
 ?>
```

So what can I do to get the result in MainActivity.java or what else can I do to check the response and forward the user to next activity?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: Please note that the way you have written the login script it is totally useless. Anyone can login even without a user account.

Comment: Yes I have written it for testing purpose... and will change that and improve the security... and please don't down vote I already have less reputation and I am beginner...

Answer (score 1):

Call your desired Activity from onPostExecute!

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution works but I don't want to comeback again to the same activity when user presses back button... How can I use finish() in this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the result and do the following to go to next intent
Which is the Activity you want to open

Replace the DisplayMessageActivity.class with required one.

```
 String result = fetchedResult;
        String successMessage = "Login Success..Welcome \".$name";
        if (result.equals(successMessage)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish(); //To remove the login screen from backstack

        }
```

Comment: this if() logic is I have already thought but I want to pass/get the result from BackgroundActivity.java to MainActivity.java in order to check with this if condition

Comment: How would I get the result in your fetchedResult variable...?